# Detect Event in any control into the FORM VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

just now I was trying to capture the F1 key on the form, but only managed when the form is selected, and I need to detect it in any form control

I used this code:

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.F1
        MsgBox("Right")
        e.Handled = True
End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [Form.KeyPreview=True](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) - If it is true then form will receive all key events.